# moving android SDK installation folder

Tags: android, adt, facebook-android-sdk

I have installed my Android SDK in Program Files (x86). But due to some reason I want to move it to D:. I want to ask if I can do that without altering my current projects on eclipse and will I have to reinstall my ADT plugins??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just move the sdk folder to where you want it, and in Eclipse's preferences, point to the new SDK location (in the Android section). ADT should still work since its installed in another location. You will need to update your paths as well if you use some of the SDK tools from the command line.

Comment: I do no know about exe file (if you have installed SDK from exe file) but for zip file you can do this without any problems. So I guess if you have installed this from exe file you won't also have problems.

Answer (score 5):

robertly is correct, just make sure you follow a few additional steps:

1. Stop adb service by runnning "adb kill-server" from command prompt.
2. Shut down anything that might be using the android sdk folder (AVD, ASDK Manager ...)
3. Copy Android folder to new home.
4. Open command prompt at new "Android\android-sdk\platform-tools" and enter "adb devices (that will fire up the adb service).

Bob's ya uncle! Hope it helps.